# Proxmox cannot route port from network bridge

Tags: networking, iptables, proxmox

I set up proxmox instance, all is working fine but i have a problem with port forwarding

i have:

**server A** with PUBLIC IP 1.2.3.4 and it's dedicated server (proxmox)

**server B** (VM on server A) in bridge with ip: 10.10.10.7

my goal is to route 1.2.3.4:5022 -> 10.10.10.7:22

my network config

```
# network interface settings; autogenerated
# Please do NOT modify this file directly, unless you know what
# you're doing.
#
# If you want to manage parts of the network configuration manually,
# please utilize the 'source' or 'source-directory' directives to do
# so.
# PVE will preserve these directives, but will NOT read its network
# configuration from sourced files, so do not attempt to move any of
# the PVE managed interfaces into external files!

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4/26
        gateway <masked>
        up route add -net <masked> netmask 255.255.255.192 gw <masked> dev enp0s31f6

iface enp0s31f6 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:10b:234d::2/64
        gateway fe80::1

auto vmbr99
iface vmbr99 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

    post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
    post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    #port forwarding
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s31f6 -p tcp --dport 5022 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.7:22
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i enp0s31f6 -p tcp --dport 5022 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.7:22
```

iptables

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5022 to:10.10.10.7:22
```

`telnet 10.10.10.7 22` works

`telnet localhost 5022` doesnt work

`telnet 1.2.3.4 22` doesnt work

Anyone could help me with that? I'd like to learn about networking but couldn't find anything related

Comment: So Server A is the proxmox right? Are you testing on/from the proxmox as itself as well?

Comment: @TomYan Could you tell more what you mean?

Comment: I think you need to tell more (or really clarify) what you mean. While you stated that `it's dedicated server`, what you posted seem to indicate that Server A is the proxmox VM host itself while Server B is a VM running on it. If that's not the case, you would need to clarify on how Server A and the proxmox VM host is connected and what exactly does this port forwarding even mean. And what I implied was, `nat/PREROUTING` does not affect traffics from a host itself, so if you are running the `telnet` commands on it instead of some other host, you'll need an equivalent rule in `nat/OUTPUT`.

Comment: @TomYan yeah, server A is proxmox and server B is VM running on server A

Comment: What network setup is in the VM? Most importantly, does it have `10.10.10.1` as a default gateway set?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov each exacly, vms have access to the internet so its properly configured

Comment: Did you try to test this from *external* IP address, not from the Proxmox host itself? Locally generated packets never traverse `PREROUTING` chains; for it to work from the host, you had to *also* put the DNAT rule into the `OUTPUT` chain of the `nat` table: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ... -j DNAT --to-destination ...`. See [the diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)